# Scroll View with multi child

Tags: java, android, ide, scrollview

I want to make a page with a several text and images.
but when I put them in the scroll view, says "ScrollView can only have one child widget. If you want more children, wrap them in a container layout."
I do not understand well what shoud I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this as a scrollview can have only one direct child, you have to put a viewgroup like linearlayout, relativelayout, etc.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNoInternet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/check_your_internet_connection"
                android:textColor="@color/black_transparent_60"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
         </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```